# Batch script to search a string in multiple xml files

Tags: windows, batch-file, search

I wrote a batch script to search a string "Error" in multiple XML files in a folder.

I'm using a for loop to iterate through all the files and using a find command to search the specific string in those files.
But, I see that the searching of string in a particular file happens only after one complete iteration instead of at the line where the find command is written. It doesn't give correct output.

I wrote the following script (Windows):

```
cd C:\Logs\
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 
for /r . %%g in (*.xml) do ( set xml_file_name=%%~nxg 

 find /I "Error"  "C:\Logs\!xml_file_name!"
 if %errorlevel%==0 ( 
   echo Error found at C:\Logs\!xml_file_name!
 ) else (
   echo No Error found.
   exit )
 )
```

There are about 10-15 xml files and if there is a string "Error" in a xml file it should output "error found" else "no error found" for each file.

Please help me with the correct code.

Comment: If XML files are in the directory of `C:\Logs`, then why the use of `for /r` to recurse into directories? This makes the later path of `C:\Logs\!xml_file_name!` suspicious as it could be an invalid path. `%errorlevel%` is being evaluated before the use of `find` so you need delayed expansion with the variable to become `!errorlevel!`.

Comment: This worked, thank you for the solution.

Comment: A much simpler solution is `findstr /MI "error" C:\Logs\*.xml || (echo no errors found)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an exit in „else“ case? So it quits after first „no error found“

EDIT: try this:

```
echo off
cd C:\Logs\
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 
for /r . %%g in (*.xml) do ( set xml_file_name=%%~nxg 

    find /I "Error"  "C:\Logs\!xml_file_name!" > nul & if errorlevel 1 ( 
        echo No Error found.
    ) else (
        echo Error found at C:\Logs\!xml_file_name!
    )
)
```

Comment: But while executing, errorlevel is always equal to zero therefore it doesn't go to else block. For every file it outputs "error found at"

Comment: Would you mind accepting the answer if it is correct? Thx!